# Sorting an array of strings using pointers (followup)

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, insertion-sort

This is a follow-up to [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172900/sorting-an-array-of-strings-in-c-using-insertion-sort/172948#172948).

Things I've changed:

1. The number of strings is checked.
2. I'm using pointers now.

I'll use `fgets` in more mission critical situations. For a lab assignment, the `scanf` approach will suffice I hope.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LEN 100
#define WID 80

void sort(char *s[], int n);

void display(char *s[], int n);

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    char *s[LEN];
    printf("Enter number of strings : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter strings one by one :\n");
    if (n > LEN) {
        printf("Sorry, maximum strings allowed is %d. Defaulting.", LEN);
        n = LEN;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d : ", i + 1);
        s[i] = (char *) malloc(WID * sizeof(char));
        scanf(" %s", s[i]);
    }

    printf("The initial elements are:\n");
    display(s, n);
    sort(s, n);
    printf("The elements after sorting are:\n");
    display(s, n);

    return 0;
}

void sort(char *s[], int n)
{
    char *temp;
    int item, i;

    for (item = 1; item < n; item++) {
        temp = s[item];
        for (i = item; i > 0 && strcmpi(s[i - 1], temp) > 0; i--);
        memcpy(&s[i + 1], &s[i], (item - i) * sizeof(char *));
        s[i] = temp;
    }
}

void display(char *s[], int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s ", s[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Any alternative or more elegant approach is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to [cast the result of `malloc()`](//stackoverflow.com/q/605845).  A `void*` can be assigned to any other kind of pointer in C, so write

```
        s[i] = malloc(WID); // no need to multiply by sizeof char -
                            // that's 1, by definition
```

However, it *is* necessary to test that the result of `malloc()` is not null:

```
        s[i] = malloc(WID);
        if (!s[i]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
```

I would recommend swapping the order of the following outputs, as the feedback on the number of inputs belongs before the instruction to start entering values.  I'd write

```
if (n > LEN) {
    printf("Sorry, maximum strings allowed is %d. Defaulting.", LEN);
    n = LEN;
}
printf("Enter strings one by one :\n");
```

I didn't fully read the algorithm of your `sort()` (I recommend you learn to use the Standard Library `qsort()`, but perhaps you want to experiment with algorithms?); however, I would note as a style issue that if you use a `for` loop with an empty statement, it's helpful to put the empty statement on its own line, thus:

```
        for (i = item;  i > 0 && strcmpi(s[i-1], temp) > 0;  i--)
            ;
```

This makes it more obvious to the reader that the following statement is not part of the loop.  It may also be worth a comment to indicate that the empty statement is intentional, as an accidental stray `;` is a common mistake.

Answer (score 2):

**Advice 1**

I suggest that you add the `{` and `}` to loop/conditional block even in the case it's a one-liner. The reason is if someone maintains your code and need to add a statement or a couple, they do not need to type those.

**Advice 2**

The `display` may print a more friendly text:

```
void display(char *s[], int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n\n[");
    char* separator = "";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s%s", separator, s[i]);
        separator = ", ";
    }
    printf("]\n\n");
}
```

For example: `[abc, bb, def]`.

**Advice 3**

If you need to sort large array of strings, there are more efficient algorithms especially for sorting strings. See [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115274/string-merge-sort-in-java). Also, I believe radix sort would perform good as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Radix sort?  What mapping would you recommend from strings to the small integer values that radix sort needs?

Comment: @Toby Speight Use each char as an integer.

Comment: @coderodde and I want to know why Linux kernel project suggest to not use `{  }` in one statement condition?

Comment: @EsmaeelE Reread the **Advice 1**.

Comment: @coderodde they say not use `{   }` you say use . ....

Comment: @EsmaeeIE What Linux kernel project has to do with this post?

Answer (score 2):

#### Bad use of memcpy

Your call to `memcpy()` uses two pointers with overlapping memory:

> ```
>     memcpy(&s[i + 1], &s[i], (item - i) * sizeof(char *));
> ```

I'm surprised that your program even works at all because `memcpy()` normally doesn't work properly in a situation like that.  You should be using `memmove()` instead.

[Here is some further reading if you need more information on memcpy vs memmove.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415910/memcpy-vs-memmove)

#### Addendum

I built and ran your program.  It uses the nonstandard `strcmpi()` function, which leads me to believe you are using a Microsoft based compiler.  This might explain why your program works for you (because the Microsoft `memcpy()` deals with overlapping memory correctly).

I replaced `strcmpi()` with `strcasecmp()` and built with gcc, and this is the result when I ran your program:

```
Enter number of strings : 5
Enter strings one by one :
1 : e
2 : d
3 : c
4 : b
5 : a
The initial elements are:


e d c b a

The elements after sorting are:


a b b b b
```

Notice how the array got corrupted to be `a b b b b` due to the overlapping `memcpy()`.